# Why does Java allow two (or more) enums to be referenced when only the last is recognised?

Tags: java, enums

I stumbled across this and was wondering is there a reason that java allows it.

Here is a sample of what I mean:

```
public enum Days {MONDAY, TUESDAY, WEDNESDAY, THURSDAY, FRIDAY, SATURDAY, SUNDAY}

public class EnumTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        methodThatDoesSomething(Days.FRIDAY);
    }

    public static void methodThatDoesSomething(Days day){

        System.out.println(day);
    }
}
```

The output for this is `FRIDAY`, as would be expected.

If I change the code like so:

```
public class EnumTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        methodThatDoesSomething(Days.FRIDAY.MONDAY);
    }

    public static void methodThatDoesSomething(Days day){

        System.out.println(day);
    }
}
```

The output for this is `MONDAY`.

I also receive the warning:

> The static field Days.MONDAY should be accessed in a static way

but it still compiles and runs.

Any example of when this multiple enum reference could be used would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This isn't a matter of enums in particular - it's just about *any* static member also (unfortunately) being valid via an expression of that type. The most common example is:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(...);
thread.start();
thread.sleep(1000); // This doesn't do what it looks like
```

For a non-enum example which is closer to your original, it's basically like this:

```
class Foo {
   public static final Foo X = null;
   public static final Foo Y = new Foo();
}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Foo foo = Foo.X.Y;
    }
}
```

Note that even though `Foo.X` is null, you don't get a null pointer exception here, although strangely the generated code *does* still access `Foo.X` before ignoring it completely. It's as if it's written:

```
Foo ignored = Foo.X;
Foo foo = Foo.Y;
```

Basically, this was a mis-step in language design for Java, and it's too late to fix it now - the best we can do is get warnings and then fix the code to access static members via the class name.

Answer (score 2):

The code works as expected, but not what you really asked for.

```
Days.FRIDAY.MONDAY
```

is just like

```
Days.MONDAY
```

But accessing `MONDAY` from a non static reference instead of static reference as you should
( and that's the reason for the warning)

Comment: If `Days.MONDAY` is used there is no warning. I only receive the warning if two or more enums are referenced like `Days.FRIDAY.MONDAY` or `Days.FRIDAY.TUESDAY.MONDAY`.

Comment: Yep. that's exactly what I've said. Days.MONDAY is static (and good) when Days.FRIDAY.TUESDAY.MONDAY is non-static (and not so good)

Comment: I get that. It is more the fact that `Days.FRIDAY.TUESDAY.MONDAY` is non-static. I was under the impression (but maybe I'm wrong) that in my enum declaration: `public enum Days {MONDAY, TUESDAY, WEDNESDAY, THURSDAY, FRIDAY, SATURDAY, SUNDAY}` that all 7 days were implicitly static. This is why the error was surprising to me.

Answer (score 1):

An enum is actually a class with special syntactic sugar to make it's usage simpler.

You are actually accessing an instance of Days which is actually Enum, and then accessing that instance's static class member.

So this is possible due to class hierarchy and Java's class static member handling.